# Can I give a docker container ssh access to a host without also giving it the private key?

Tags: docker, ssh

#### Request

This docker command injects my ssh key and username into a container, connects that container to a remote host, and then runs: `echo hello world` on the host:

```
docker run --rm \
    -e "host=the.host" \
    -e "user=my.user.name" \
    -v "/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa:/key" \
    ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash -c \
        'apt update && apt install -y ssh \
         && ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$host -i /key
             echo hello world'
```

I want the command to be able to connect to the remote host, but I **don't** want it to be able to `cat /key` and see my ssh key.

What changes can I make to achieve this?

---

#### Context

I'm writing a test runner.  My code is responsible for determining which tests can be run against which hosts, but the test itself might not be written by me (it gets pulled in from a git repo when my test runner starts up).

I am **not** worried about my colleagues abusing the server with their test code because that abuse would be visible in source control.  They are semi-trusted in this case.  I **am** worried about somebody writing a test which causes my ssh key to appear in log output somewhere.

Ideally, I would set up the ssh connection first, then create the container--somehow granting it access to the connection, but not the key.

Comment: "I want the command to be able to connect to the remote host, but I don't want it to be able to cat /key and see my ssh key." - these two requirements don't go together.

Comment: @rdas why not?  Letting somebody into your house is not the same as giving them the key.  The rule is: you can modify this server, but you must commit code to do so, you can't log in and mess around at a shell.  (actually, they can, but they'll have to use their own keys to do so).

Comment: You asked about SSH (where this won't work) - not physical locks and keys (where this sort of works). SSH needs the private key to authenticate the client to the server. It needs to read the key(something you want to avoid) & then compute something that it will send to the server. Hence they don't go together - in SSH.

Comment: I see, I thought you were telling me that it was conceptually contradictory.  Incompatibility with how SSH works--that's useful info, thanks.

I was kind of hoping for some way to connect a container to a host that mimicked the way you can connect two containers to each other (docker calls them links).

Comment: What you could do (although I don't know your exact usecase – what should actually happen instead of `echo hello world`?) is using a second container to build an SSH tunnel, forward ports, and then using this container's exposed ports to access some service on the remote host. This way, your "actual" container would not need the SSH key. As I mentioned, I cannot estimate if this is suitable for your setup.

Comment: @bellackn I like that idea, thanks.  One of the things that might happen instead of `echo hello world` is that a test might try to ssh to the target server (Ansible does this under the hood, for example).  Ideally such an ssh attempt would succeed without prompting for creds since it is coming through an already-established tunnel, but I don't know how to make that happens.  Perhaps I can trick ansible into using telnet in this case, because for everything except subsequent ssh connections, your solution would work.

Comment: @rdas I've since learned that ssh does support this.  See my answer if curious.

Comment: The user isn't restricted to just *one* key pair for connecting to the host; you can generate a second pair meant to be used *only* by this container, and if the image ever gets compromised, you can disable the pair.

Comment: @chepner That was going to be my plan B.  I avoided it not because it has any technical deficiencies, but because certain people in my org would object to automation that configures their servers to be more open.  Functionally it's about the same, but politically it feels different.

Comment: I do like your answer, as it keeps any key out of the image in the first place. I might still suggest generating a second pair, as it doesn't tie the image to any pre-existing use of the same key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature I needed was [SSH Multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) which I learned about [here](https://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2010/02/ssh-controlmaster-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/)

This file goes in the docker image at `~/.ssh.config`

```
Host foo
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm_socket/%r@%h:%p
```

And this file goes on the host:

```
Host foo
    HostName foo.bar.com
    User my.username
    IdentityFile /path/to/key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm_socket/%r@%h:%p
```

I called the image `keylesssh`, so this command creates a container which **doesn't** have the key, but **does** have the folder which will contain a socket if there is an existing connection.

```
docker run --rm \
    -v "/home/matt/.ssh/cm_socket:/root/.ssh/cm_socket" \
        keylesssh /bin/bash -c 'ssh dev1 hostname'
```

It comes together like this:

1. I open an ssh connection from the machine that is hosting the docker daemon to the remote host
2. SSH will creates a socket and put it in ~/.ssh/cm_socket with a predictable name
3. I create a container, sharing that folder with it
4. The container tries to ssh to the host, notices that the socket exists, and uses the existing connection without authenticating--no key required
5. Once the test has finished running, the container shuts down
6. When my code notices the container shutting down, I kill the master ssh connection

I know it works because the `hostname` command resolves the hostname of the remote server, not of the container or of the docker host.

Comment: I've found this to be not very portable.  I think it's because if you copy a socket around it doesn't necessarily work like a socket anymore.  It works if you're mounting the host's docker socket into the outer container and then letting that container create the ssh socket, which mounts to the inner container.